# Query Parser - eDisMax - split and phrase

Tags: solr, lucene

`harry potter and chamber of secrets` when passed through standard `eDisMax` produces query like `(keywords:harry) | (keywords:potter) | (keywords:chamber) | (keywords:of) | (keywords:secrets)`.
However I want the query to be `(keywords:harry) | (keywords:potter) | (keywords:chamber) | (keywords:of) | (keywords:secrets) | (keywords: harry potter and chamber of secrets)`.
It seems default Lucene parser creates these terms. Can I somehow configure query to have both split on whitespace and phrase. Then boost the phrase kind of query?
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using `<str name="ps">10</str> <str name="pf">keywords</str>`.
What this essentially does is it will create a phrase query with slop 10.
example: `DisjunctionMaxQuery(((keywords:\"harry potter and chamber of secrets\"~10))))/no_coord"` with all the other queries created as in question.

Comment: Explained here https://solr.pl/en/2010/07/14/solr-and-phrasequery-phrase-bonus-in-query-stage/